# Are manaburn and damage-on-the-stack used in Pre-Modern?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There is a format called [Premodern](https://www.premodernmagic.com/) which uses sets from 4th Edition until Scourge. Modern Magic lacks such rules as mana burn and combat damage on the stack. What Magic rules flavour should I be using when playing Premodern?

Comment: Gah! Now I feel old! I last played... sometime before graduating the university, which was in 2007. I never even noticed that manaburn isn't a thing anymore... and hasn't been for over 10 years! 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The site you link to suggests the use of contemporary magic rules, and also gives a [list of reasons](https://premodernmagic.com/blog/why-premodern-uses-contemporary-rules/) why:

1. The contemporary rules are better
2. It’s confusing to use different rules in different formats
3. Contemporary rules enables digital and sanctioned play
4. There is no natural set of old rules
5. Using a mix of contemporary and old rules sets is inelegant

Answer (score 4):

There have been so many changes to the rules that they are more of a continuum than a set of clearly defined points, and the choice of which rules to include is essentially arbitrary.

The most clearly recognizable landmark change was the [6th edition overhaul](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Sixth_Edition/Rules_changes) that introduced the stack among many other changes. Before then, the game was sufficiently different as to be a different game, which means you should expect a significant learning curve if you want to play faithfully by the older rules, and you can't expect too much outside support in case rules questions do arise.